# How to get the most recent snapshot of the Blob Storage in the Blob Triggered Function app?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am trying to receive the latest snapshot of the blob and compare it against the latest blob content to get the delta/ the content updated(either deleted, removed or new content added to the file, file has json content in it). For this, I'll need to get the latest snapshot and was seeing if the azure sdk provides the feature to do so?

Here is the implementation logic:

```
 BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("foo");
 BlobClient blob = containerClient.GetBlobClient(pathtotheblobcontentfileinthecontainer);          
 var resultSegment = containerClient.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: PREFIX+path, states: BlobStates.Snapshots);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'll need to get the latest snapshot and was seeing if the azure sdk
> provides the feature to do so?

SDK does not provide this feature. What you will need to do is fetch all snapshots for a blob. This will return a list of blob snapshots in ascending order (i.e. from oldest to newest).

Once you have this list, you will need to reverse that list so that you get the newest snapshot as the first element of that list.